# Performing http web request to a server requiring SAML authentication

Tags: saml, claims-based-identity

I have simple app that is trying to do a http web request to a server that requires SAML authentication. Authenticated users will get a http response header with a special token, which is what I need to ultimately get.

My app is .net based and does a pretty simple http web request. It does the request then parses the response header. I later traverse the header for the specific token I need:

```
...
try
{ 
  WindowsIdentity identity = HttpContext.User.Identity as WindowsIdentity;
  HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
  req.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
  req.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
  req.Timeout = 30000;
  HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
  if (response == null)
  {
      throw new Exception("No HTTP Response");
  }

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  Byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
  Stream rStream = response.GetResponseStream();
  int count = 1;
  do
  {
    count = rStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
     if (count != 0)
     {
        sb.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, count));
     }
  } while (count > 0);
  ...
```

The problem is that the server I'm requesting requires SAML authentication. It redirects to an ADFS server upon request. My app server currently uses kerberos authentication but I can enable it to do SAML as well. Both servers use the same IdP (ADFS) and are in the same enterprise.

My question is - since my app can also do SAML on the same IdP, is there anyway I could get the necessary claims to connect directly into the destination server?

Comment: What do you mean by connect claims directly? Do you want to configure claims to return attributes in SAML?